# Looking for the exact opposite of path-to-regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, routes

I am building some API connector, and I'd like to be able to generate fetch URL easily.

My idea is to base my solution on the [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) lib syntax, so that for exemple `injectParams('/foo/:hello', { hello: 'world'})` return `'/foo/world`

Is there an existing library to do such an injection ?

Comment: Are you using any framework? Or do you just need a library to do this?

Comment: I am thinking of a library, as simple as `path-to-regexp`. I am building a React using `react-boilerplate` (so it is served by a small express app) to be precise, but any pure js or node package is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here I'm replacing each key (having prefix :) with it's value in path variable.

```js
function injectParams( path , obj )
{
    for( var key in obj ){
      var rgx = new RegExp(':' + key + '\\b', 'g');
      path = path.replace( rgx, obj[key] );
    }
  return path;
}
var result;
result = injectParams('/foo/:hello', { hello: 'world'})
console.log( result );
// prints  "/foo/world" in console 

result  = injectParams('/foo/:hello/:another', { hello: 'world',another:'wroking'});
console.log( result );
//   prints  "/foo/world/workng" in console

result  = injectParams('/foo/:hello/:another/:hello/:hello', { hello: 'world',another:'wroking'});
console.log( result );
//   prints "/foo/world/wroking/world/world"

result = injectParams('/foo/:a-b', { "a-b": 'world'})
console.log( result );
```

Comment: The replace line has few problems:
* If the there are two variables and one is a prefix of another, it will fail.
* if a variable occurs more than once, it will stay unreplaced.
It's better to use something like this:
path.replace(new RegExp(':' + key + '\\b', 'g'), obj[key])
assuming the variable name doesn't contain any RegEx special chars.

Comment: @JánHalaša can you give me an example of where it will break ?

Comment: @JánHalaša oh okay. I missed that one. let me update to your solution. Thanks for noticing :).

Comment: Now it works fine exept if you pass this { ".*" : "test" }

Comment: @MaciejKozieja yes,that is an exceptions. but it works well enough with special symbols.

Comment: @JimishFotariya My point is that creating multiple regex expresion is less eficient then using one, in this method for evry key in object you have to iterate whole length of string.

Comment: @MaciejKozieja this will consume a very very small fraction of time.Even if he has URL of 1000's of character long, still its very fast.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135410/discussion-between-maciej-kozieja-and-jimish-fotariya).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's the "easy" case. `path-to-regexp` provides more syntax, such as the optional params (`:param?`). Anyway 
I think that if there is no existing lib to do so, I'll build my own based on the answer given here, since it's an easy but interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace all occurrences of :key

```js
const injectParams = (path, obj) =>
  path.replace(/:\w+\??/g, x => {
      const val = obj[x.replace(/:|\?/g, '')]
      if(val != undefined) return val
      else if (/\?/.test(x)) return ''
      else throw new Error(`Value for '${x}' not specified.`)
  })

  console.log(injectParams('http://stackoverflow.com/:post?', {}))
  console.log(injectParams('http://stackoverflow.com/:post?', {post: 1}))
  console.log(injectParams('http://stackoverflow.com/:post', {})) // throw error
```

### How it works

`/:\w+/g` find all :keys.
`.replace(/:\w+\??/g, x => ...` result of searching for `/:\w+\??/g` is passed to function and it has to decide with with value it should be replaced.
`...obj[x.replace(':','')])` extract key value from object

Comment: Try injectParams('/foo/:a-b/', { "a-b": 'world'}) .

Comment: @JimishFotariya I asumed that key must be made out of word chars thats why it wont work but this would fix it, just replace `/:\w+/g` with `/:[-\w]+/g`

Comment: Then it will break with &

Comment: More it will break with any char that is not ment to be there it will break event with numbers but this is benifitial because u can chain them like for example this `/foo/:hello/:hello#:foo-and-:hello` Its simply desined to be like this.

Comment: but this shouldn't be visable in url it's more about what you prefer i decided to replace keys that are not found in object with "" because it makes more sens for me and for example `http://stackoverflow.com/:post` would make more sence to not keep :post at the end while no value for it is specified.

Comment: @MaciejKozieja `injectParams('http://stackoverflow.com/:post, {})`should throw, since `post` is a mandatory parameter. To provide more context, my goal is to build an API url generator: a missing parameter would generate an incorrect URL, so it should throw.
However `:post?` should be indeed replaces by `''` if post is absent.

Comment: @EricBurel so you want keep evrything unless its folowed by `?` ?

Comment: @EricBurel if I understood corectly thats what you wanted, check edit.

Comment: @MaciejKozieja I did not test yet but that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

`path-to-regexp` currently has [compile](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v6.2.0#compile-reverse-path-to-regexp) api